# trying to calculate price of rooms * tax (const double 0.06) getting error on console

Tags: c++

i am trying to calculate price of rooms and tax price for simple program everything works , just at the end when i program calculate tax with total price of rooms, i get wrong answer on the console.

## the rooms and tax:

```
int  small_rooms {0};
int  large_rooms {0};
const double price_of_small_room{25.0};
const double price_of_large_room{35.0};
const double tax_price {0.06};
```

======================================================

## the actual calculation

```
cout << " cost: "  << (small_rooms * price_of_small_room) + (large_rooms * price_of_large_room) << endl;
cout << " tax: " <<  ( (small_rooms * price_of_small_room) + ( large_rooms * price_of_large_room) )* tax_price << endl;
cout << " =================================== " << endl;
cout << " total estimate " << (small_rooms * price_of_small_room)  + (large_rooms * price_of_large_room) * (tax_price) << endl;
```

===================================================================================

screenshot:
(look at the end , the total price after tax is wrong at bottom)

http://floomby.io/s/091119/Nfi45lzx?a

Comment: You're calculating something entirely different in the last line. How about some variables to store calculated values?

Comment: Don't post links to images! *All* relevant info needs to go in the question, as *text*.

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow.com must include all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Suspicious links to dodgy external web sites can stop working at any time rendering the question meaningless. For more information, see [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When you say... "*i get wrong answer on the console*"... What answer do you get in the console? Please add this to your question post, along with the answer you **expect** to get in the console!

Answer (score 0):

In the last line the parantheses are wrong. Probably you want to add the tax to the sum of both costs. Why make it so compilcated? Just use some more variables:

```
auto cost = (small_rooms * price_of_small_room) + (large_rooms * price_of_large_room);
auto tax = cost * tax_price;
auto total = cost + tax;

cout << " cost: "  << cost << endl;
cout << " tax: " << tax << endl;
cout << " =================================== " << endl;
cout << " total estimate " << total << endl;
```

Comment: may i know why are you using auto and not char?

Comment: When using `auto` the compiler will determine the type of the variable for us. `char` on the other hand is the smallest datatype the language knows, why should we use it?